# Kendo Async Upload : File displays even after clicking Remove

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am uploading files through Kendo Upload. On uploading a file and then clicking on remove, the *RemoveCircular* method of controller is called and it duly deletes the file from server.

However the Filename and Remove button are still displayed though they should be removed as well.

Is there anything I'm missing here? Thanks for help.

The code in .cshtml is as below.

```
<div class="controls-trck">
  @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
  Name("UploadCircular")  
 .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:220px" })                     
 .Multiple(false)
 .Async(a => a
    .Save("SaveCircular", "DB0010062")
    .Remove("RemoveCircular", "DB0010062")
    .AutoUpload(false)
     )                                                                                  
  ) 
</div>
```

Code in Controller:

```
public ActionResult RemoveCircular(string[] fileNames)
{
  foreach (var fullName in fileNames)
  {
     //Delete Files
  }
  return Content("");
}
```

Comment: Are there any JS errors in the console? What is the status code that you returned? Try to return empty object as JSON to signify success.

Comment: No JS errors that I could find. I am returning blank content Content(""), as per Kendo example. RemoverCircular executes successfully and deletes the files, so no issues there. So I should return empty Json instead of Content?

Comment: Thanks Petur! Returning Json instead of Content worked. If you can set your comment as ans I can mark it as such.

Comment: Can u post the complete code to remove file .Help needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like empty response is treated like as an unsuccessful response. Try to return empty JSON instead.